# How to read multiple successive tables from ONE file by R language?

Tags: multiple-tables

What should I do to read multiple successive tables from ONF file (e.g. CSV format), each table with one blank line and headers on top, like:

X1 X2 X3

1 2 3

4 5 6

(blank line)

Y1 Y2 Y3

2 4 5

3 7 9

Comment: I think I understood your problem but can you at least expand your question?

Comment: Hi. I need to read large TXT files, each containing multiple tables in the format I described. How I can read these tables separately? If there is not a straightforward method, what do you suggest?

Comment: Is your question **really** related to multithreading anyway?

Comment: Sorry. I wanted to add something elsr, but I had changed to this automatically!

Comment: Sorry. I wanted to add something elsr, but it had changed to this automatically!

Answer (score 0):

This is very trivial. Except for the `multithreading` tag which has currently no link with the body of the question, this can be achieved by correct design of the process.

Try to draw the scheme on a sheet of a paper and/or use pseudo code. (You didn't even mention implementation language). Use status variables to track what table you are reading. On the beginning, set to the first table. When you find the line is a blank like change that status variable to the next table.

On each data row you read from a file, check the status variable and apply proper decoding.

Ultimately return all the tables, perform DB actions and so on...

Comment: The language is R. As you may know, R has functions to read tables with headings. But they read the whole file or a specific number of lines. While the number of lines are variable among tables, even the number of columns is diff sometdifferentimes.

Comment: My answer then is totally useless. Anyway why not splitting file in multiple temporary files so they can be processed separately?